# Purpleair.com map doesn't display on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile-safari

The webpage [Purpleair.com](http://Purpleair.com) contains a link to a map displaying realtime reports of air quality. The map is located [here](https://www.purpleair.com/map?opt=1/mAQI/a10/cC0&select=28299#13.13/36.95866/-122.04236). The map displays correctly on Safari 13.1.2 running under macOS Catalina.

The map doesn't display in iOS. I can navigate to the Purpleair main page with iOS Safari, but after selecting the "Map" link, the map itself does not appear. Instead, the screen redraws and displays this:

[image]

What might I do to enable the map to be viewed on the iPhone? The iPhone is an SE (2d generation), running iOS 13.6.1. Location Services on the iPhone is enabled for Safari.

Comment: I just tried with the direct link on 13.6.1. First I got the same view a you did but a split-second later the map got drawn. In Firefox it worked immediately. Hmm.

Comment: Works for my iPhone 8+, iOS 13,61, on Safari, Chrome and Firefox

Comment: Thanks. I hard-restarted the phone, and tried again with screen lock turned off so the thing stayed live. After ten minutes, no map. So far, it's a mystery.

Comment: I tried Firefox, and the map loaded immediately. Hmm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to enable Java Script. In Settings > Safari > Advanced > Enable Java Script, move the switch to the right. The map loaded immediately.